# Get list of months from a given Quarter Excel

Tags: excel

So I have done some digging around and cannot seem to find an answer to my question.

Basically, I want to be able to extract which months Fall within a given Quarter.

the Given quarter is automatically provided by using the

> "=ROUNDUP(MONTH(date)/3,0)"

formula. Now what i want is in 3 other cells the 1st, 2nd and 3rd month that fall into this quarter

for example

```
B3 = =ROUNDUP(MONTH(date)/3,0) = 2

C4 = April (1st month that falls in B3)
D4 = May (2nd Month that falls in B3) 
E4 = June (3rd Month That falls in B3)
```

OR

```
B3 = =ROUNDUP(MONTH(date)/3,0) = 3

C4 = July (1st month that falls in B3
D4 = August (2nd Month that falls in B3)
E4 = September (3rd Month That falls in B3)
```

Any Idea or pointers would be really appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Confusing `=ROUNDUP(MONTH(date)/3,0) = 2` again `=ROUNDUP(MONTH(date)/3,0) = 3` ! Same formula but output different 2 and 3, how?

Comment: it was supposed to show that the Quarter had changed so the same formula then showed that the current Quarter was now 3 not 2. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula in `C4` cell and Drag and Right

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(NOW()),$B$3+COLUMN(B$3),"01"),"MMM")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change the cell range accordingly

```
=IF($B$1=1,"January",IF($B$1=2,"April",IF($B$1=3,"July","October")))
=IF($B$1=2,"May",IF($B$1=3,"August",IF($B$1=4,"November","Feb")))
=IF($B$1=2,"June",IF($B$1=3,"September",IF($B$1=4,"December","March")))
```

'[image]

Comment: This Worked Perfectly!